# Authentication to Drupal REST Server returns unauthorized

Tags: 7

I am working on a Drupal CMS configured as follows:

```
Code base: Drupal 7.54

Modules:
Services 7.x-3.19
Services API Key Authorization 7.x-1.12
REST 7.x-3.19
```

I have setup an endpoint under services and when I have authentication turned off I have no issues accessing the endpoint.

When I turn on API Key Authentication and when I attempt access I get a 401 unauthorized access.

I have the API Key access type set to Header. Here is the result when I run this curl command with the -v from the command line:

```
curl -v -i -H "Accept: application/json" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "Authorization: HTTP_API_KEY=ahfs-7fp-AGq_e97Gps8Zg" http://dev00.chgo.pat.com.local/api/skus

* Trying 192.168.0.53...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to dev00.chgo.pat.com.local (192.168.0.53) port 80 (#0)
> GET /api/skus HTTP/1.1
> Host: dev00.chgo.pat.com.local
> User-Agent: curl/7.51.0
> Accept: application/json
> Content-Type: application/json
> Authorization: HTTP_API_KEY=ahfs-7fp-AGq_e97Gps8Zg
> 
< HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized : Unauthorised access.

HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized : Unauthorised access.
< Date: Thu, 04 May 2017 20:05:53 GMT
Date: Thu, 04 May 2017 20:05:53 GMT
< Server: Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu)
Server: Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu)
< X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
< Expires: Sun, 19 Nov 1978 05:00:00 GMT
Expires: Sun, 19 Nov 1978 05:00:00 GMT
< Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate
Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate
< X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
< Content-Location: http://dev00.chgo.pat.com.local/api/skus
Content-Location: http://dev00.chgo.pat.com.local/api/skus
< Vary: Accept
Vary: Accept
< Content-Length: 24
Content-Length: 24
< Content-Type: application/json
Content-Type: application/json

< 
* Curl_http_done: called premature == 0
* Connection #0 to host dev00.chgo.pat.com.local left intact
["Unauthorised access."]
```

I get the same result using Postman.

I've also tried using HTTP_API_KEY: ahfs-7fp-AGq_e97Gps8Zg

Is my error an incorrectly formatted request or do I have something incorrectly setup on the server?